# Python Pandas does not recognize numbers when read from .txt file

Tags: python, c++, pandas

I'm using Pandas to write to table from .txt file generated by other C++ program. Python or Pandas do not recognize them as numbers and I'm really clueless what to do. Here is Python code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\romea\Desktop\Inżynierka\ER_etap_5\Metropolis_average_path_6_p_0.010000_nodes_100.txt', sep='\t', engine='python', header=None)
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.drop([0])
df.head()
```

[![Head of data frame][1]][1]

And here it is when i try plot it:

```
plt.scatter(df["iteracja"], df["variancja"])
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Check out that values on y-axis are nonsens.
Here is the .txt file. Separation with "\t" and new line with std::endl from C++:

```
iteracja    krawedzie   srednia_chwil   variancja
0   10000   10000   0.138686
100 2843.07 2843.07 0.991797
200 16.0296 16.0296 0.263918
300 4.55257 4.55257 0.235237
400 4.5834  4.5834  0.217816
500 4.68072 4.68072 0.167809
600 4.78377 4.78377 0.129301
700 4.83168 4.83168 0.109151
800 4.8534  4.8534  0.0963009
900 5.66296 5.66296 0.0710574
1000    5.96965 5.96965 0.0485687
```

And here is the part of C++ code that generates it:

```
myfile<<"iteracja"<<"\t"<<"krawedzie"<<"\t"<<"srednia_chwil"<<"\t"<<"variancja"<<endl;
        std::vector <float> temp_curent;
        std::vector <float> temp_edges;
        for(int i = 0; i<break_counter; i++)
        {
            temp_curent.push_back(current_average_array[i]);
            temp_edges.push_back(edge_array[i]);
            if (i % 100 == 0)
            {
                double suma = 0;
                double suma_edges = 0;
                for(int j = 0; j<temp_curent.size(); j++)
                {
                    suma_edges += temp_curent[j];
                    suma += temp_curent[j];
                }
                suma /= 100;
                suma_edges /= 100;
                cout<<i<<"\t"<<suma_edges<<"\t"<<suma<<"\t"<<variance_fractorial[(int)((i/100))]<<endl;
                myfile<<i<<"\t"<<suma_edges<<"\t"<<suma<<"\t"<<variance_fractorial[(int)((i/100))]<<endl;
                temp_curent.clear();
                temp_edges.clear();
            }
        }
        myfile.close();
        return break_counter;
```

Comment: Please post sample data as text and maybe a link to the text file. From the C++ code it looks it's enclose in quotes.

Comment: are you sure values are not in quotes?

Comment: Which values? In C++ code I'm sure they are not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv(r'your_file_here.txt', sep='\t', header=0)
plt.scatter(df["iteracja"], df["variancja"])
plt.show()
```

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you, kind stranger. Could you tell me why it makes a difference?

Comment: I was getting errors with your code (not a wrong chart) and just wrote it like I would - it works